# How 'heavy' is it on the server to run mysql commands every few seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, server

I have a set of data that is used by GUI for positions and stuff, and that positions are also stored in MySQL. Every time the data changes, it is reflected on the server too.

Then if I want to update MySQL as frequent as jquery (or javascript, I don't know) tracking "mousemove" motion, that is, send request to the server that for every "mousemove" change the value in MySQL, how 'heavy' is it, especially when multiple users are using the same server?

What would be a better solution? I'm thinking of waiting for 3 seconds until the motion is finished, then if there is no more motions, sending request to the server then.

Although multiple people aren't using my server, but this always concerns me and hinders me from progressing. Please help.

Comment: "How fast is [X]?" We don't know, benchmark it and see.

Comment: There's no need to be mean. OP doesn't know the difference between Javascript and jQuery -- so tell them! (jQuery is a Javascript library used for DOM manipulation and AJAX). As for the other comment, yes, you do need to benchmark. It's impossible for us to tell how fast something will be without code to benchmark. Besides that, I'm curious: why do you need to hit the database every time the GUI is updated?

Comment: Doing those SQL updates/inserts will likely be quiet heavy. Have you ever used a remote desktop (other than RemoteDesktop which doesn't use a remote mouse cursor IRC) application? Ever notice the mouse lag? That's just sending the coordinates. Any reason you need to store mouse coordinates?

Comment: it depends on how complicated the query is, but as a rule of thumb always try doing the following in frontend: send the request only if changes have been made actually + introduce a delay after watching for keyboard/mouse actions. e.g. if you're implementing a search-as-you-type, add something like 200-300ms delay before performing actual search.

Comment: In this vein, you may want to look at "debounce" functions that will wait for input to stop for you.

Comment: Use socket or solution like firebase, better way to do that things I guess..

Comment: Mouse positions?  Can you just store this in localstorage or the DOM?  Why does it need to be recorded in a server side DB?

Comment: @BrandonG I think I wouldn't have asked this question if I knew a 'client side MySQL' that already has query commands to deal with data stored on the user side. So, I think I'm prone to use MySQL when things can be done on the client side.

Comment: @ajpocus Regarding your first comment, please refer to my comment to BrandonG (above). And do you mean "debounce" function as explained in here? [davidwalsh's site](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

Comment: @user3290525 so you could store things on the client side, you just don't know how? And yes, that's the debounce function I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to have an intermediate in-memory solution to mitigate the number of database calls. Eg. `Memcached`. But! but! before we begin, lets have some numbers.

So lets do the Math, shall we?

You want to track the events to their details.

```
| Action to be recorded       | Frequency of Occurrence  | Per user/minute avg. |
|:---------------------------:|:------------------------:|:--------------------:|
| 1. MouseMove!!! (Seriously?)|             Very Heavy!!!|                   200|
| 2. Clicks (MouseDown)       |            Medium to High|                    10|
| 3. Hover (MouseOver)        |                      High|                    50|
```

So with a very rough ball park estimate for one active user the total `events` fired for a specific session would be `260/per minute`.

So for lets say `10 concurrent users` your events per minute become `2600`.

*And this becomes a sure fire way of DDoS(ing) your own server.*

Some useful hints.

1. Try to log the events in batches, ie. log the events as they occur on the client-side and once a threshold is crossed send a request to server to log that batch.
2. Do not use your main application server for this kind of logging, because this thing is -- wait for it -- **logging** and you should use a separate server for maintaining logs.
3. As said earlier, on the server too, implement an in-memory store of logs before pushing them to the database.
4. This data **doesn't** even need to be stored in a `Relational DB`. Nearly all big companies use `flat DB`(`NoSQL`) for storing this kind of info.
5. If you still decide to proceed with `relational DB`, when doing the `INSERT`s use `Transactions`.
6. If the tracking is to be done for only the logged in users, and a dedicated in-memory cache is not feasible for you, you could store the tracking data in user's session, and again after a threshold move the records to DB.

Comment: Socket or solution like firebase ?

Comment: Oh, using threshold seems like a good idea. I think I tend to prefer MySQL because I don't know any "client-side MySQL" or library that handles data in MySQL-query-way.